# closing select2 on click away when closeonselect is false

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

is there a better way to close select2 when you click away?  I have it closing with

```
$(document).click(function(event) { 
    if(!$(event.target).hasClass("select2-selection__rendered") &&
       !$(event.target).hasClass("select2-results__option")) {
        $("#e1").select2('close');
    }        
});
```

but that seems weird.

here is the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/jEADR/5557/

Comment: did you figure it out? I have the same problem, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52297349/select2-does-not-close-the-choices-box-on-clicking-outside-it-with-closeonselec One more issue: If you have several Select2's, I want to target the exact one to close, rather than hard-code ID I want to get the dropdown described by this Select2. Is that possible without a lot of jQuery selection magic?