# Select2 does not close the choices box on clicking outside it (with closeOnSelect=false)

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/776660/

When the choice box is open, if you try clicking anywhere outside **on the level of the choice box**, it doesn't get closed. However, if you click outside on the level of the Current-Selection line, then it does get closed.

How can I force the Select2 choice box to close when any outside click is performed, including on the level of the choice box?

P.S. I am using the `closeOnSelect: false` option to keep the choice box always open during the selection process -- but it should still close on an outside click,

```
$('#dropdown').select2({
    closeOnSelect: false
});
```

**Another similar question** - [closing select2 on click away when closeonselect is false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49466671/closing-select2-on-click-away-when-closeonselect-is-false)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't know what causes the problem, but adding this to your CSS 'fixes' it

[Select2 Issue 4939](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/4939)

```
html,
body{
  height: 100%;
}
```

Updated code

```js
/* Scroll CurrSel SPAN to bottom on every Select2 Select event */
$('#dropdown').on("select2:selecting", function(e) {
  var currselspan = $('#dropdown').next().find('.select2-selection--multiple').first();
  console.log('scrollTop = ' + $(currselspan).scrollTop() + ' scrollHeight = ' + $(currselspan).prop('scrollHeight'));
  $(currselspan).scrollTop($(currselspan).prop('scrollHeight'));
});



$('#dropdown').select2({
  closeOnSelect: false,
});
```

```css
.select2-selection--multiple {
  height: 2rem;
  max-height: 2rem;
  overflow: auto;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div style="width: 50%">
  <select id="dropdown" style="width: 100%" multiple>
    <option>TEST ELEMENT 1</option>
    <option>TEST ELEMENT 2</option>
    <option>TEST ELEMENT 3</option>
    <option>TEST ELEMENT 4</option>
    <option>TEST ELEMENT 5</option>
    <option>TEST ELEMENT 6</option>
    <option>TEST ELEMENT 7</option>
    <option>TEST ELEMENT 8</option>
    <option>TEST ELEMENT 9</option>
    <option>TEST ELEMENT 10</option>
    <option>TEST ELEMENT 11</option>
    <option>TEST ELEMENT 12</option>
    <option>TEST ELEMENT 13</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, that fixed it. I also tried a custom `$(document).click()` handler but it could never intercept my clicks in that area, so I had to go with this CSS solution.